# jchart2d error building Drake on apple silicon

Tags: drake

I recently ran into the following errors after an update when building Drake on apple silicon:

```
ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_russt/9c100c86c1cc4c543d01c45f7a63d5c6/external/_maven_net_sf_jchart2d/BUILD:7:12: Extracting interface @_maven_net_sf_jchart2d//:_maven_net_sf_jchart2d failed: (Exit 1): ijar failed: error executing command external/remote_java_tools_darwin/java_tools/ijar/ijar external/_maven_net_sf_jchart2d/jchart2d-3.3.2.jar ... (remaining 3 arguments skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox
src/main/tools/process-wrapper-legacy.cc:80: "execvp(external/remote_java_tools_darwin/java_tools/ijar/ijar, ...)": Bad CPU type in executable
Target //:install failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_russt/9c100c86c1cc4c543d01c45f7a63d5c6/external/optitrack_driver/lcmtypes/BUILD.bazel:33:17 Building external/optitrack_driver/lcmtypes/liblcmtypes_optitrack.jar (7 source files) failed: (Exit 1): ijar failed: error executing command external/remote_java_tools_darwin/java_tools/ijar/ijar external/_maven_net_sf_jchart2d/jchart2d-3.3.2.jar ... (remaining 3 arguments skipped)
```

The operative line here being `ijar failed: error executing command`.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that my `adoptopenjdk` installation was broken.  Running

```
brew reinstall --cask adoptopenjdk
```

exposed the error (I needed to run `sudo softwareupdate --install-rosetta` to resolve it).

This also exposed the fact that [adoptopenjdk is now deprecated on homebrew](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/16779).